# How to parse string to array in Spark?

Tags: arrays, json, apache-spark

How to flatten Array of Strings into multiple rows of a dataframe in Spark 2.2.0?

Input Row `["foo", "bar"]`

```
val inputDS = Seq("""["foo", "bar"]""").toDF
```

inputDS.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Input Dataset `inputDS`

```
inputDS.show(false)

value
-----
["foo", "bar"]
```

Expected output dataset `outputDS`

```
value
-------
"foo" |
"bar" |
```

I tried `explode` function like below but it didn't quite work

```
inputDS.select(explode(from_json(col("value"), ArrayType(StringType))))
```

and I get the following error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'jsontostructs(`value`)' due to data type mismatch: Input schema string must be a struct or an array of structs
```

Also tried the following

```
inputDS.select(explode(col("value")))
```

And I get the following error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`value`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not StringType
```

Comment: If you simply have an Array of string then you do not need the `from_json` part. Simply try `inputDS.select(explode(col("value")))`.

Comment: Tried that earlier and tried it again just now. I get the following error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`value`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not StringType`

Comment: Looks like you do not actually have an Array, but a string. An option would be to look into the `split` function and use that together with `explode`. Can you check the input again and update the question?

Comment: updated and that is exactly what I have and those are exact errors I get

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exception is thrown by:

```
from_json(col("value"), ArrayType(StringType))
```

not `explode`, specifically:

> Input schema array must be a struct or an array of structs.

You can:

```
inputDS.selectExpr(
  "split(substring(value, 2, length(value) - 2), ',\\s+') as value")
```

and `explode` the output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue above should be fixed in Spark 2.4.0 (https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24391)
So you can use this `from_json($"column_nm", ArrayType(StringType))` without any problems.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply achieve using flatMap.

```scala
val input = sc.parallelize(Array("foo", "bar")).toDS()
val out = input.flatMap(x => x.split(","))
out.collect.foreach{println}
```

Comment: sorry this is not what I am looking for since this is not how I have it in my code. The question here is a simple version of my bigger problem.

Comment: I did not give you a down vote. I am not sure who did